# What is wrong with the set method of my LinkedList

Tags: java, collections, arraylist, implementation

Im trying to implement a linkedlist.. All of my methods work except for the set method. It is only supposed to change the replace the element at the given index. But after setting the element in the index it is making the rest of the elements in the list to null, can anyone point out what I'm doing wrong in the set method?

```
        public class LArrayList<E> {

            private static class Node<E> {

                Node<E> next;

                E data;

                public Node(E dataValue) {
                    next = null;
                    data = dataValue;
                }

                @SuppressWarnings("unused")
                public Node(E dataValue, Node<E> nextValue) {
                    next = nextValue;
                    data = dataValue;
                }

                public E getData() {
                    return data;
                }

                public Node<E> getNext() {
                    return next;
                }

                public void setNext(Node<E> nextValue) {
                    next = nextValue;
                }
            }

            private Node<E> head;
            private static int listCount;

            public LArrayList() {

                head = new Node<>(null);
                listCount = 0;
            }

            public void add(int index, E e) throws IndexOutOfBoundsException{

                if (index < 0 || index >= listCount + 1) {

                    throw new IndexOutOfBoundsException("Bad index, please use index within range");
                }
                else{


                Node<E> positionTemp = new Node<>(e);
                Node<E> positionCurrent = head;

                for (int i = 0; i < index && positionCurrent.getNext() != null; i++) {
                    positionCurrent = positionCurrent.getNext();
                }

                positionTemp.setNext(positionCurrent.getNext());
                positionCurrent.setNext(positionTemp);
                listCount++;
            }
            }

            public E set(int index, E e) throws IndexOutOfBoundsException {

                if (index < 0 || index >= listCount) 
                    throw new IndexOutOfBoundsException("Bad index, please use index within range");


                Node<E> positionTemp = new Node<>(e);
                Node<E> positionCurrent = head;

                for (int i = 0; i < index; i++) {
                    positionCurrent = positionCurrent.getNext();
                }


                positionCurrent.setNext(positionTemp);

                return positionCurrent.getData();

            }

    public E get(int index) throws IndexOutOfBoundsException
    {

        if (index < 0 || index >= listCount)
            throw new IndexOutOfBoundsException("Bad index, please use index within range");

        Node<E> positionCurrent = head.getNext();
        for (int i = 0; i < index; i++) {
            if (positionCurrent.getNext() == null)
                return null;

            positionCurrent = positionCurrent.getNext();
        }
        return positionCurrent.getData();
    }



            public static void main(String[] args) {

                LArrayList<String> aa = new LArrayList<String>();
                aa.add(0, "0");
                aa.add(1, "1");
                aa.add(2, "2");
                aa.add(3, "3");
                aa.add(4, "4");
                aa.add(5, "5");


                System.out.println("The contents of AA are: " + aa);    

                 aa.set(0, "a");


                System.out.println("The contents of AA are: " + aa);    



                 System.out.println(aa.get(0));

                 System.out.println(aa.get(1));

                 System.out.println(aa.get(2));
                 System.out.println(aa.get(3));

                 System.out.println(aa.get(4));

                 System.out.println(aa.get(5));

        //OUTPUT IS: The contents of aa are: [0][1][2][3][4][5]
        //The contents of AA are: [a][b][c][d][e]
        //a
        //A
        //null
        //null
        //null
        //null

            }

        }
```

Comment: Why have you posted all that irrelevant code? Have you tried using a debugger?

Comment: From what I can tell, you're not preserving the links in your list.  Try calling `set(0, new Object())` on a list of size 10 or more; you will not have any access to the other, now orphaned objects.

Comment: sorry about that! i removed all the irrelevant code

Comment: Where is the list get method?

Comment: you might be able to see it now!

Answer (score 1):

After a quick look over your code:

```
 positionCurrent.setNext(positionTemp);
```

Don't you need to also link *positionTemp* to the element after it?

Answer (score 1):

First get the item just before current index:

```
           for (int i = 0; i < index; i++) {
                positionCurrent = positionCurrent.getNext();
            }
```

You are missing a link between currently set item and rest of your list, Establish that by:

```
 positionTemp.setNext(positionCurrent.getNext().getNext());
 positionCurrent.setNext(positionTemp);
```

And return

```
 positionCurrent.getNext().getData()
```

Hope it helps.

Comment: the -1 was messing up the index.. but the rest of the code did the trick! thanks sanjeev!

Comment: Glad that helped you. have fun coding :)

Answer (score 0):

ok, so you have many problems in your code, i will help you with some but not all.
I really advise you to use Eclipse debugger(If you use eclipse), check this out:
http://www.vogella.com/tutorials/EclipseDebugging/article.html

First of all, the reason that your whole list is null after a set is that your index is 0 than you use a for loop that does nothing(cause the index is 0), so in the line after that:

```
                positionCurrent.setNext(positionTemp);
```

You are setting head's next to be positionTemp, and than you are loosing the rest of the list cause you are not setting next for postionTemp(postionTemp next is null)

second, when you are adding the first item to the list, or when the list is empty and you are adding something, you need to make this new node the list's head, otherwise your list head will always be null.

third, when you want to print list, you cant use:

```
                System.out.println("The contents of AA are: " + aa);
```

You need to do this instead:

```
    Node<E> head = aa.head;
    while(head != null){
        system.out.println(head.data)
    }
```

It looks like you have more bugs on your code, so i simply advise you use debugger.
Good luck

Comment: i think the add method works fine, the list head is not empty when the add method is called..

Comment: It's not, the head's data is null, cause that is what you do when you create a new list, print you list or debug the code and you will see